# ¿Cómo combinar comandos sed? O como sustituir por diferentes condiciones?

Tags: linux, shell, sed

Quiero realizar múltiples sustituciones al mismo tiempo, generé este tipo de sustituciones de a una.

```
sed 's/NPQ/\ NPQ/g' | sed 's/qNP/\ qNP/g' | sed 's/qP/\ qP/g' | sed 's/ETR/\ ETR/g'
```

El comando es mucho más largo, tiene otras 20 sustituciones más. ¿Cómo lo condenso en un único comando? No logro encontrar la sintaxis adecuada

Comment: `sed -e 'comando1; comando2'`. Por ejemplo, `sed -e 's/h/H/; s/l/L/' <<< "hola"`

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Creo que eso deberías colocarlo como una respuesta.

Comment: @eftshift0 es que es exactamente lo que se indica en las respuestas a la pregunta que sugiero como duplicada. Creo mejor marcarla como duplicada, por tanto